# How do I get to the "Personnel Facilities" waypoint in Priority: Mars?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the second mission of the game, Priority: Mars, you fight your way inside a building and go up a large elevator. Once you take the elevator all the way up, you find yourself in an area that kind of looks like a big garage. Some enemies attack you from the walkways above and, once you defeat them, a waypoint appears to "Personnel Facilities." Shepard makes a comment about figuring out a way up there, and then that's where I get stuck.

I found a button that raises one of the large yellow vehicles but then I run around all over the floor of area and can't find a ladder or any other way of reaching the walkways above. The only thing I can find is an elevator the enemies have conveniently sabotaged.

So, with all that said, **how do you get from the floor of the "garage" to the "Personnel Facilities" waypoint above?**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have lifted up "one of the large, yellow... things..." you can scale the boxes to the left of it and jump on top of it to reach the top floor of the room.
Here is a video of Ronan Forman doing it